# Why were the contents of the HTML file sent as the response to this AJAX request (with Node server active)?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, server, listeners

Here's the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.12.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="page.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's the page Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
    };
    xhr.open('GET', '');
    xhr.send();
});
```

Here's the Node server Javascript:

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.statusCode = 200;
  response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  respone.write('Hello, dog');
  response.end();
}).listen(80);
console.log('Server is running!!');
```

When I launched the HTML page and checked out the console, it had printed the contents of the HTML page (i.e., starting with `<!DOCTYPE html>`).  I was trying to get it to print "Hello, dog" from the Node server but it seems as if the server's response somehow got trumped, perhaps because the browser was effectively listening for a response from the HTML file through the same port.

What's odd is that if I change the url of the GET request to the server Javascript file, it will actually return the contents of that file.  Also, if I add a button and make the AJAX request occur with the click of the button (i.e., the page would have already loaded at that point), the HTML file contents still print to the console.

I'm just experimenting to see how all of this works.  Specifically, I'm trying to get my page Javascript to interact with my Node server without using HTML as the medium for requests and responses.  I'm still working through the Treehouse AJAX course, but in general I'm having trouble finding resources about setting them up to communicate.  Most of the resources seem to deal with one side or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what is provided above, I'd only expect to see "Hello Dog" when you navigated to localhost:80 in your browser. That is all the server is capable of returning. If you wanted your route to serve your static index page, you'd have to, while not recommended, do something like this:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('./index.html', function (err, html) {
    if (err) {
        throw err; 
    }       
    http.createServer(function(request, response) {  
        response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
        response.write(html);  
        response.end();  
    }).listen(80);
});
```

However, as mentioned, this is not recommended. In general your going to want to have some sort of [middleware](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html) to help with the plumbing for things like serving content and routing. By far I think [express](http://expressjs.com/) is the most common. This is a quick overview of [routing](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html) and another about serving [static content](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html). There are loads of free resources out there to help one along.